# TF401289: The current user does not have permissions to create tags, even if owner and administrator

Tags: azure-devops

when trying to create a new tag within a work item I get the error "TF401289: The current user does not have permissions to create tags." even if I am the Owner of the Organization and Administrator of all Projects.

Permission for "Create tag definition" is set to allowed within Security for all Teams.

What do I have to do to prevent the error?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Regards,
Andi

Comment: Could be inheritance issue, check the parent branch.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Permission for "Create tag definition" is inherited allowed. Regards, Andi

Answer (score 2):

You may only have a Stakeholder license level. From Stakeholders can only assign existing tags to work items (can't add new tags) and can only save queries under My Queries (can't save under Shared Queries).

> Stakeholders can only assign existing tags to work items (can't add new tags) and can only save queries under My Queries (can't save under Shared Queries).

Ensure that you are at least at the Basic license level

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I am licensed by a MSDN Enterprise Subscription.

Regards,
Andi